# To run a flv file without loop

Tags: html, flv, flash-video

I am new to run a **.flv** file. I used a tutorial for this. The link of the tutorialhttp://www.fieg.nl/embed-html5-video-with-flash-fallback#file-index.html

Here the *video* file is repeating time to time. I think it is in a loop. How can the video file run once when open the window. The code for run the *flv* file is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                 var v = document.createElement("video"); // Check if the browser supports the video tag
                 if ( !v.play ) { // If no, use Flash.
                        var params = {
                             allowfullscreen: "false",
                             allowscriptaccess: "always",
                             wmode: "transparent"
                        };

                        var flashvars = {
                             src: "demo.flv"
                        };

                        swfobject.embedSWF("http://localhost/TantraProjects/Ranjit/html5/demo_flv.SWF", "demo-video-flash", "270", "296", "9.0.0", "http://localhost/TantraProjects/Ranjit/html5/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);
                 }
                 else {
                        // fix for firefox not looping
                        var myVideo = document.getElementById('demo-video');

                        if ((typeof myVideo.loop == 'boolean')) { // loop supported
                             myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                                  this.currentTime = 0;
                                  this.play();
                             }, false);
                        }
                 }
            });
</script>
```

Please help me to know more about it.

Hi i have got the same thing for the video. There is a loop in the video and i dont want to looping the video.My html for the code.

```
<div id="demo-video-flash"><!-- wrapped in a div for the flash fallback -->
   <video id="demo-video" height="155" width="270" autoplay loop>
      <source src="http://localhost/TantraProjects/Ranjit/html5/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!-- MPEG4 for Safari -->
      <source src="http://localhost/TantraProjects/Ranjit/html5/demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> <!-- Ogg Theora for Firefox 3.1b2 -->

      <!-- this is the image fallback in case flash is not support either -->
      <img src="http://localhost/TantraProjects/Ranjit/html5/demoo.png"/>
   </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using JW Player, correct? Then you should add `repeat: none` to the flashvars so it would look something like this.

```
var flashvars = {
      src: "demo.flv",
      repeat: "none"
};
```

More details on the 'flashvars' params [over here.](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12536/configuration-options/)

Comment: I have added the repeat: "none" to my code, but it did not work.

Comment: Hi JakeGould I cleared my cookie, but still i got the looping